# misclassification error for segmented image

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I am working on image segmentation and i want to evaluate my work using misclassification error which equals

```
ME = 1- (|b0 intersect bt|+ |f0 intersect ft|)/(|b0|+|f0|)
```

where BO and FO denote the background and foreground of the original (ground-truth) image, BT and FT denote the background and foreground area pixels in the test image.

i don't know how to discriminate object from background, and how to generate a scaler value.
I am working on matlab. I will appreciate any help. it is urgent.

Comment: i need help with evaluation, i have segmented image and a ground truth image and  i need to find misclassification error for segmented image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `nnz` command, you can easily count the number of non-zero pixels in an image. Assume you have a segmented image `si` and a ground truth image `gt`, both of which are binary images, with ones wherever there is signal, the mis-classification can be written as

```
ME = 1 - (nnz(~gt & ~si) + nnz(gt & si))/(numel(gt));
```

In the denominator, you just put the total number of pixels, since that's the sum of background plus foreground.

Comment: thanks for replay. I am working on multilevel thresholding and i find that if i have G as ground truth image and T as thresholded image I can find ME by    G xor T which make all similar pixels = 0 then count nonzero pixels.